# Constructing Lagrangian from the Hamiltonian

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, mathematical-physics, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian

Given the Lagrangian $L$ for a system, we can construct the Hamiltonian $H$ using the definition $H=\sum\limits_{i}p_i\dot{q}_i-L$ where $p_i=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}_i}$. Therefore, to determine, $p_i$ we need to know $L$.

Now suppose, we are given the Hamiltonian $H$. Can we then reconstruct the Lagrangian $L$? Certainly the relation $L=\sum\limits_{i}p_i\dot{q}_i-H$ is not helpful because there is no prescription how to determine $p_i$ without knowing $L$.

Comment: The Legendre transform is involutive

Comment: @Phoenix87 that is clear, but the problem here is that it seems that the OP has H written in terms of q and its time derivative, not of p and q: it not clear how to invert Legendre because OP has no way to know H(q,p).

Comment: The answers below explain how the Legendre transform works.

Comment: @Phoenix87 the problem is: if you have H(q, dot(q)), and not H(q,p), how to reconstruct L? Certainly they explain how Legendre works, but the interesting part of the question is still unanswered: "Certainly the relation L=... is not helpful because there is no prescription how to determine p without knowing L"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, there exists a Legendre transformation from $g(p)$ to $f(x)$:
$$
f(x)=p(x)x-g(p(x))
$$
with $x=dg/dp$. Here the notation $p(x)$ means $p$ written in terms of $x$. In your case, the Hamiltonian is a function of $p$ and you are transforming it to a function of $\dot{q}$, so you must use Hamilton's equation to get the velocity:
$$
\dot{q}_i=\frac{\partial H}{\partial p_i}
$$
which you then solve for $p$ (so that it's a function of $\dot{q}$, e.g. $p=h(\dot{q})$). You then have your Lagrangian as
$$
L(q,\dot{q})=\dot{q}_ih(\dot{q}_i)-H(q,h(\dot{q}))
$$

For the (relativistic) Hamiltonian<sup>1</sup>,
$$
H(q,p)=\sqrt{p^2c^2+m^2c^4}+V(q)
$$
the momentum should be 
$$
p(\dot{q})=\frac{m\dot{q}}{\sqrt{1-\dot{q}^2/c^2}}
$$
which was computed using $\dot{q}=\partial H/\partial p$ & then inverting to get $p$ in terms of $\dot{q}$. You should verify that this is correct (but it does look right to the relativistic momentum, $p=\gamma mv$). Then you can just do the substitution and get your Lagrangian.

<sup>1. This particular Hamiltonian was included in [version 2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/revisions/190471/2) of this question, but was since removed; as it still provides an example of the $H\to L$ transform, I kept it in.</sup>

Comment: "Certainly the relation L=∑pq'−H is not helpful because there is no prescription how to determine pi without knowing L." This means that we are given H in terms of q and its derivatives, so it is a "pre-hamiltonian": we have no direct access to p.

Comment: @Quillo [OP's own post begs to differ](https://physics.stackexchange.com/revisions/190471/2), though it was later edited out. The fact that it was accepted as the answer suggests they were satisfied with the response.

Comment: The quote is present also in the previous version... then OK, there is also the relativistic H bit. But to me the interesting part of the question is that one. Certainly the OP can accept everything they want. I am commenting to hope that the question gets a bit of activity to discuss also this point, maybe I will consider a bounty :)

Answer (score 12):

First of all, the hamiltonian contains the coordinates $q_i$ and their momenta $p_i$. You have to calculate the velocities $\dot{q}_i$. For that, you'll need the Hamilton-Jacobi equations $$\dot{q}_i = \frac{\partial H}{\partial p_i}$$The Legendre transform, as noted in the comments, is involutive, so the lagrangian is just the Legendre transform of the hamiltonian $$L = \sum_i p_i \dot{q}_i - H$$ where you have to express everywhere the momenta in terms of the velocities.

Worked-out example: harmonic oscillator. The well-known hamiltonian is $$H = \frac{p^2}{2m} + \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2 q^2$$ From the Hamilton-Jacobi we get (unsurprisingly) that $$\dot{q} = \frac{\partial H}{\partial p} = \frac{p}{m}$$ And plug it in the Legendre transform
$$L = \dot{q}p - H = \dot{q}(\dot{q} m) - \frac{(\dot{q}m)^2}{2m} - \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2 q^2 = \frac{1}{2}m \dot{q}^2 - \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2 q^2$$Which is indeed the lagrangian for the harmonic oscillator.

Comment: Note: this answers the first version of the question, wich didn't mention the relativistic hamiltonian. As Kyle addressed this point before me, I won't expand my answer.

Comment: I have removed the second part because now the strategy of answering that is obvious

Comment: The problem is that H is written jn terms of q and its derivatives, not in terms of p and q.

Answer (score 7):

Let us suppress explicit time dependence $t$ from the notation in the following. [Hamilton's eqs.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics) are the [Euler-Lagrange (EL) eqs.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) for the so-called Hamiltonian Lagrangian

$$\tag{1} L_H(q,\dot{q},p)~:=~ p_i\dot{q}^i-H(q,p).$$

In other words, the solutions to Hamilton's eqs. are stationary points for the Hamiltonian action

$$\tag{2} S_H[q,p]~:=~\int \! dt~L_H(q,\dot{q},p). $$

Next define the Lagrangian as

$$ \tag{3} L(q,\dot{q})~:=~\sup_p L_H(q,\dot{q},p). $$

Formula (3) is the succinct answer to OP's question about how to construct the Lagrangian from the Hamiltonian.

The [Legendre transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_transformation) (3) is often referred to as integrating out$^1$ the momentum variables $p_i$. Then the action (2) becomes

$$ \tag{4} S[q]~:=~\int \! dt~L(q,\dot{q}). $$

The stationary points of the action (4) are given by the EL eqs. for $L$.

--

$^1$ If we go beyond classical mechanics, and consider the phase space path integral formulation, then "integrating out the momentum" is exactly what is happening.