# What is the difference between variational principle, principle of stationary action and Hamilton's principle?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, terminology, variational-principle, action

In advanced mechanics, we learn about the variational principle, the principle of stationary action, and the Hamilton's principle. I feel that the difference between them is not very clearly organized in my mind. Can somebody explain them that will help me organize them? For example, whether one principle is more basic and general than the other two, whether one can be derived from the other etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [principle of stationary/least action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary-action_principle) usually$^1$ refers to [Hamilton's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%27s_principle) $\delta S=0$.  Hamilton's principle is an example of a [variational principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_principle).

--

$^1$NB: Note that e.g. Goldstein calls the principle of abbreviated action/[Maupertuis's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maupertuis%27s_principle) $\delta \int {\bf p}\cdot \mathrm{d}{\bf q}=0$ for the principle of least action, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/127320/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: Isn't Hamilton's principle more general than the principle of stationary action which applies to the Lagrangian $L(q,\dot{q}, t)$ only? I thought Hamilton's principle also applies to some other function of the form $f(q,p,\dot{q},\dot{p},t)$.

Comment: So does the principle of stationary action, cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/190561/2451), so no difference there.