# Lagrangian in terms of evolution function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, time-evolution, propagator

If the time evolution function $K(A,B;t)$ is such that $$\psi(A;t) = \int K(A,B;t)\psi(B;0)dB.$$ We know that this function has all the information about how systems evolve. So from this we should be able to determine the Hamiltonian or the Lagrangian.

Then the Hamiltonian *operator* can be defined in terms of this as $$i\hat{H}\delta(A,B) = \dot{K}(A,B;0).$$ Here I put $\hbar=1$. I think this is the best we can do. To determine the Hamiltonian in terms of conjugate momenta would require anti-commuting variables.

This follows from $$\psi(t) = e^{-i t \hat{H}}\psi(0).$$

I was trying to find the Lagrangian $L[A]$ in terms of the $K(A,B;t)$

The best I could come up with is the horrible looking limit:

$$L[A]=L(A,\dot{A}) = \lim_{u\rightarrow 0} \left(\frac{\dot{K}(A+ u \dot{A} , A ; u )}{K(A+ u \dot{A} , A ; u )} - \frac{\dot{K}(0, 0 ; u )}{K(0 , 0 ; u )} \right)$$

which probably only works for zero dimensional systems. Is there a known simpler expression for the Lagrangian in terms of the evolution function (also sometimes called the propagator in non-relativistic cases).

The question is, is there a better formula than this? (Assuming this formula is correct)

Edit: Deleted unnecessary information.

Comment: As I said, I do disagree with your expressions. You should then recast your question as: "given all matrix elements of the hamiltonian, how do you find the corresponding Lagrangian"? It is *absolutely* crucial to avoid any and all path integral tangents, which would only reinforce misconceptions.

Comment: OK, I deleted unnecessary information. But I disagree, I am not asking about matrix elements of a Hamiltonian. I am asking for a formula directly from the propagator to the Lagrangian - simpler than the limit I made.

Comment: The limit you made is misguided, as ̂ eigenvalues *A,B* are not time-dependent. The classical limit of the Hamiltonian leads to the (classical!) Lagrangian, normally, [cf](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/190471/constructing-lagrangian-from-the-hamiltonian).

Comment: No, what I'm doing is just inserting time dependent fields $A(t)$ into the function K.  No, we must use the quantum mechanics Hamiltonian, the classical Hamiltonian does not preserve the anti-commuting quantities.

Comment: Fields? You are assuming a wavefunctional Schrödinger equation? Quantum Hamiltonian-Lagrangian function, instead of plain Lagrangian? Anticommuting quantities? You must probably specify all this in your question

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand your expressions. Let's  nondimensionalize to  $\hbar=1$ and consider your eigenvalues *A,B* of $\hat x$, which, of course, do not depend on the time. Functional integration is overkill here.

The conventional [definition of the propagator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator#Non-relativistic_propagators) is but
$$
K(A,B;t)\equiv \langle A| \hat U(t)|B\rangle= \delta(A-B) -it \langle A| \hat  H|B\rangle + O(t^2), 
$$
so that the coordinate matrix elements of the Hamiltonian are just
$$
\langle A| \hat  H|B\rangle =i\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{K(A,B;u)-\delta(A-B)}{u}=i\dot{K}(A,B;0), \qquad \leadsto \\ \hat H = \int\!\!dAdB~~|A\rangle \langle A|\hat H|B\rangle \langle B|~,
$$
from which you may transition to the Lagrangian, if needs be, in the standard manner.

For the free particle, you should be able to reproduce
$$
\langle A| \hat  H|B\rangle = -\frac{\partial_A^2}{2m} ~\delta(A-B)~.
$$

Comment: Yes, you have reproduced the Hamiltonian in terms of K which I already did just rewritten it in terms of bra-ket notation. I'm looking for the Lagrangian in terms of K. There is a lot of complicated equations hidden in the simple phrase "you may transition to the Lagrangian, if needs be, in the standard manner". This gets us no closer to writing a formula for L in terms of K.  Sorry.

Comment: I assume you appreciate how the classical limit of the operator hamiltonian determined through the matrix elements above can be [instantly Legendre-transformed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/190561/66086) to the classical Lagrangian, no? E.g., $H=p^2/2m$ above...

Comment: Taking the classical limit of a Hamiltonian might lose information if we are not using anti-commuting variables? But if this is the case then I would take this as an answer if you could express it as an equation.

Comment: Lose information? What kind of nonclassical object Lagrangian do you have in mind? This is not NRQM?

Comment: A classical hamiltonian obviously has less information that a quantum mechanical hamiltonian since since we are removing the ordering. No-one said nonclassical Lagrangian.

Comment: Emphasize it in the question. In conventional NRQM, *including path integrals*, only classical Lagrangians are featured.