Deriving Lagrangian mechanics from Hamiltonian mechanics
I have just finished reading Susskind's Theoretical Minimum. I think I got it well, even found some mistakes in few equations The book starts from Newtonian Mechanics, then derives Lagrangian formalism and then Hamiltonian one, which I guess is very standard way of the subject introduction. But it kept me pondering, if we start with Hamilton's formulation, then if we are able to get Euler-Lagrange equations. I will state that in questions.

If we have any abstract system defined via Hamiltonian mechanics, is there a proof that there exists equivalent reformulation of the system in Lagrangian mechanics?
If such a proof exists, is it constructive? That is, if there is a canonical/algorithmic way of constructing the Lagrangian from a given Hamiltonian?
Can you outline the proof, show counterexample (or point to such proof/counterexample)? In case of the proof, I am especially interested in how to derive Euler-Lagrange equation from Hamilton's Equations.
Bonus question: What if we would made Hamilton's Equations more symmetric, by removing the minus sign? Does it have a deep fundamental meaning on abstract level, or does it rather comes from the fact that we want to keep the convention(is it really only a convention?) that in Newtonian Mechanics we want force to act in a direction that makes the related potential smaller?

Thank you for your answers ;)

These are perfectly reasonable questions, but you should ask them as separate questions so that others can give thorough answers to each part separately!

The first 3 are aspects of the same question.

Article by R. K. P. Zia, Edward F. Redish, and Susan R. McKay, 2009, Making sense of the Legendre transform The interconversion between Lagrangian formulation and Hamiltonian formulation is by way of Legendre transform. The authors discuss that Legrendre transform is its own inverse; when you apply Legendre transform twice you recover the original form. So it's inherently bi-directional. Another resource: blog post by Jess Riedel, 2017, Legendre transform (A bit of a rant; highly informative.)

Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/190471/2451

Note that it is in general not possible. There are singular Lagrangians that don't easily give you a Hamiltonian, and there are singular Hamiltonians that don't easily give you a Lagrangian.

Your "bonus question" does not make sense.

I will stick to the one-dimensional case, i.e. a system with a unique Lagrangian coordinate $q=q^1$. The procedure I am about to discuss easily extends to the case of many variables.
If $H(t,q,p)$ is smooth and such that the function at $t$ and $q$ fixed
$$s = \frac{\partial H(t,q,p)}{\partial p}\tag{1}$$
can be smoothly inverted, obtaining
$$p= p(s,q,t),\tag{2}$$
then
$$L(t,q,s) := sp(s,q,t) - H(t,q,p(s,q,t))\tag{3}$$
defines a Lagrangian function. The $t$-parametrized curves which —  in the variables $q,p$ — solve the Hamilton equations generated by $H$ one-to-one correspond — in the variables $q,\dot{q}:= s$ —  to the curves which solve the Euler Lagrange equations generated by $L$ above.
PROOF. A lengthy computation starting from $(3)$ produces the following three identities.
$$\frac{\partial L(t,q,s)}{\partial t}= - \frac{\partial H(t,q,p)}{\partial t}\Biggr|_{p=p(s,q,p)}\:,\tag{I1}$$ $$\frac{\partial L(t,q,s)}{\partial q}= - \frac{\partial H(t,q,p)}{\partial q}\Biggr|_{p=p(s,q,p)}\:,\tag{I2}$$
$$\frac{\partial L(t,q,s)}{\partial s} = p(s,q,p)\:.\tag{I3}$$
Now consider a curve $t\mapsto (q(t),p(t))$ which solves Hamilton's equations and its corresponding curve in the Hamiltonian setting.  $t\mapsto (q(t),s(t)):= \left(q(t), \frac{\partial H(t,q,p)}{\partial p}\Biggr|_{(t,q(t),s(t))}\right)$. The Hamilton equations are
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}p}{\mathrm{d}t}= - \frac{\partial H(t,q,p)}{\partial q}\Biggr|_{(t,q(t),p(t))}\:, \quad \frac{\mathrm{d}q}{\mathrm{d}t}= - \frac{\partial H(t,q,p)}{\partial p}\Biggr|_{(t,q(t),p(t))}\:.$$
The former Hamilton equation, using $(\text{I}3)$ on the left-hand side and  $(\text{I}2)$ on the right-hand side, can be rephrased to
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\Biggr|_{(t,q(t),s(t))} \frac{\partial L}{\partial s}= \frac{\partial L}{\partial q}\Biggr|_{(t,q(t),s(t))}\:.$$
The latter Hamilton equation, according to $(1)$, can be rephrased to
$$s(t) = \frac{\mathrm{d}q}{\mathrm{d}t}\:.$$
If we change the name of the variable $s$ to $\dot{q}$, we have the standard EL equations:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d}t}\Biggr|_{(t,q(t),\dot{q}(t))} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}}= \frac{\partial L}{\partial q}\Biggr|_{(t,q(t),s(t))}\:.$$
$$\dot{q}(t) = \frac{\mathrm{d}q}{\mathrm{d}t}\:.$$
Notice that all the procedure is reversible so that every curve that satisfies EL's equations solves Hamilton's equations when passing to Hamiltonian variables.
REMARK. The crucial point here is the invertibility of the transformation $(1)$ (at fixed $q$ and $p$). That is equivalent to the invertibility of the Legendre transformation for the Lagrangian associated with $H$. If one starts from  a singular Hamiltonian, i.e., such that $(1)$ cannot be inverted like this
$$H(q,p) = kp+ hq\:,$$
then all the above procedures cannot be used. That is the same as for singular Lagrangians, which do not admit Hamiltonian formulation.

Section in your books or in Arnol'd for the proof?

Btw for an explicit source, one can refer to Abraham, Marsden’s Foundations of Mechanics, section 3.6, for a proof of equivalence (assuming a hyperregular Lagrangian on $TQ$, we get Hamiltonian mechanics on $T^*Q$, and conversely, starting from a hyperregular Hamiltonian on $T^*Q$, we get Lagrangian mechanics on $TQ$).

Some equivalent characterizations are given in https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/759523/. I think this is closely related to Valter's approach. More details can be found as pointed out by peek-a-bo in Marsden's book.
